# about android Drawable getBounds return Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)

Tags: android, drawable

i want get the bound of drawable but then i use getBounds or copyBounds method .they all return Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0).
 the code like this

```
    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.tbar_single_pressed);
    Rect copyRect = marker.copyBounds();
    Rect getRect= marker.getBounds();
```

then the result 
copyRect is Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)
getRect is also Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)

why?   the marker is NOT null  and i have the res tbar_single_pressed....

thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drawables don't have dimensions unless they've been drawn.  If you want to get the size of the image you're passing in, you can create your own rect with `drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` and `drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()`