# Push from firebase console always got default icon (Gradle Firebase 11.8.0)

Tags: android, firebase

For firebase sdk 11.8.0, my push generated from firebase console directly to my application (which is in the background) always show default android icon but not my customized one.

It works fine when i downgrade the sdk to 11.4.2.

Anyone have the same bug?

---

update:

just test with my oneplus 3T and nokia 6, running Android 8.0 and 7.1.1 respectively.

Both use Firebase SDK 11.8.0.

Nokia 6 worked,
Oneplus 3T failed.

Not sure is mobile phone problem or Android System problem.

---

Update @ 27-3-2018


**Fix:** 
Thanks Piotr's update that this has been fixed on 12.0.0

---

Update @ 17-6-2020
revised title to describe the problem accurately

Comment: is this also happening in all android phones, or only oreo?

Comment: just test with my oneplus 3T and nokia 6, running Android 8.0 and 7.1.1 respectively. Nokie 6 goes fine with custom icon, while oneplus 3T only display default one. Not sure is mobile phone problem or Android System problem.

Comment: yes I have seen questions related to this where it is a default icon in android 8.0, so probably a bug. But should be okay in all versions before

Comment: while firebase performance requires at least sdk 11.8.0, so i am stuck on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137775/fcm-default-icon-uses-invalid-gradient check this only way is to downgrade for now

Comment: Hello Daryl Sze , I got same type of error and i also apply 12.0.0 version but it's steel not working in 8 or 8 above android version. so can you show me your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Firebase SDK bug. Should be fixed if you use 12.0.0:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180320

Comment: It's not helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in Firebase version 11.8.0 on Oreo. I was facing the same issue, but when I downgraded to version 11.6.2 it working fine for me.

And now this issue is resolved in new version 12.0.0.

Comment: It should be fixed in 12.0.0. No need to downgrade.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed in 12.0.0 now. But my answer was before this version.

Comment: I already upgrade the version 12.0.0 but it's not working. I got notification is in lower than 8 version in android.

Comment: Now firebase messaging dependancy is on latest version with more fixes like 17.x.x if you try the upgraded version then hopefully your problem will be resolved.