# React native notification icon not working on Samsung

Tags: android, react-native, samsung-mobile

After upgrading to android sdk to v26 the notification icons became white boxes, we have solved this issue by using white/transparent icons.

However, on **Samsung** phones the small icons in push notifications are green android robots. In all other phones where push notifications are using large icons (white/transparent) it works perfectly.

How can we fix the **Samsung** issue?

I am using:

- React native: 0.56 (0.55.4 too)
- React native firebase: 3.3.1
- Android Target SDK: 26

I have:

- ic_launcher.png which is a multi-color logo for the app.
- ic_notification.png which is white/transparent logo for the >Lolipop
  push notifications.

Corresponding lines in android.manifest:

```
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
          android:name = 
          "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
          android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification"
        />
        <meta-data 
          android:name = 
          "com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
          android:resource="@color/orange" 
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

We solved this after many hours by:

1. Making sure the icon is the right color and size using https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#create-notification
2. Updating our Firebase SDKs in build.gradle to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

Version `11.0.8` (and possibly others) have a [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137775/fcm-default-icon-uses-invalid-gradient) [bug](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180320), so using at least `12.0.0` should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the react-native version to 0.55.4. Newer versions may have a problem with icons.

Comment: I would add this entry in the comment but the website blocks this possibility

Comment: We have 0.55.4 on the production version of our project and still the same problem.